# PHP unserialize data empty, why is this?

Tags: php

my serialized data looks like this

```
a:6:{i:0;s:12:"Early humans";i:1;s:32:"Apes And Hominids   Dart's Find";i:2;s:36:"The hunter gatherers of South Africa";i:3;s:25:"Early Humans The Eve Gene";i:4;s:50:"Australopithecines, Homo ergaster and Homo sapiens";i:5;s:21:"Landscapes of history";}
```

When i try and unserialize, it turns out to be empty.

my code:

```
$urlnames = unserialize($row['url_name']);

foreach($urlnames as $names){

  echo $name;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should perform a check on the `unserialize()` function to ensure it unserializes correctly; If the parameter cannot be unserialized then it will return false.

Something like `if (!$urlnames = unserialize($row['url_name'])) { echo 'cannot unserialize'; }`.  If the condition is true, you will know that `$row['url_name']` does not contain the serialized array.

Answer (score 4):

The serialized string is wrong. There should be one more character in the "Dart's find" string -- I don't know why one is missing, but adding one will make it work fine.

**[See for yourself](http://www.ideone.com/Fkf0x)**.

Comment: I Relize that there is something missing, I think I'm doing something wrong on the serializing side, but don't know what.

Answer (score 1):

On index 1 you have only 31 characters that's why it isn't working.

Comment: Yes but how are the character going missing that's what I'm wondering as I'm inserting raw data.

Comment: Did you put it into an database?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get your serialized string form the db?

If you get it from there, than your backslash is missing. That's your 32th character.

more info about backslashes and databases check google/yahoo/bing ...

Comment: Yes that's it, I use addslashes() to add the backslash but when I unserialize it goes missing for some reason.

Comment: sorry i was unavailable for write a response.

You're backslash is gone when you get your info out of the db. You don't need to add slashes when you serialize. That's the concept.